# in Ubuntu how to add netboot.xyz to GRUB boot options?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, netboot

how is one supposed to add [netboot.xyz](https://netboot.xyz/) to grub boot options? right now i just do

```
sudo apt -y install ipxe;
sudo wget 'https://boot.netboot.xyz/ipxe/netboot.xyz.lkrn' -O /boot/ipxe.lkrn;
sudo wget 'https://boot.netboot.xyz/ipxe/netboot.xyz.efi' -O /boot/ipxe.efi;
sudo wget 'https://boot.netboot.xyz/ipxe/netboot.xyz-arm64.efi' -O /boot/ipxe-arm64.efi;
```

and then pick ipxe in grub, which works, but obviously isn't the way it's supposed to be done

Comment: You try a network boot over grub?

Comment: @BlockchainOffice yes, [netboox.xyz](https://netboot.xyz/) makes that super easy :)